# Parse html content for a value

Tags: java

I receive a Http response after a call as Html String and I would like to **scrape** certain value stored inside the `ReportViewer1` variable.

```
  <html>

   ....................
    ...........
<script type="text/javascript">
                var ReportViewer1 = new ReportViewer('ReportViewer1', 'ReportViewer1_ReportToolbar', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_WaitControl', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_ReportCell', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_PreviewFrame', 'ReportViewer1_ParametersAreaCell', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_ErrorControl', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_ErrorLabel', 'ReportViewer1_CP', '/app/Telerik.ReportViewer.axd', 'a90a0d41efa6429eadfefa42fc529de1', 'Percent', '100', '', 'ReportViewer1_EditorPlaceholder', 'ReportViewer1_CalendarFrame', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_DocumentMapCell', {
                    CurrentPageToolTip: 'STR_TELERIK_MSG_CUR_PAGE_TOOL_TIP',
                    ExportButtonText: 'Export',
                    ExportToolTip: 'Export',
                    ExportSelectFormatText: 'Export to the selected format',
                    FirstPageToolTip: 'First page',
                    LabelOf: 'of',
                    LastPageToolTip: 'Last Page',
                    ProcessingReportMessage: 'Generating report...',
                    NoPageToDisplay: 'No page to display.',
                    NextPageToolTip: 'Next page',
                    ParametersToolTip: 'Click to close parameters area|Click to open parameters area',
                    DocumentMapToolTip: 'Hide document map|Show document map',
                    PreviousPageToolTip: 'Previous page',
                    TogglePageLayoutToolTip: 'Switch to interactive view|Switch to print preview',
                    SessionHasExpiredError: 'Session has expired.',
                    SessionHasExpiredMessage: 'Please, refresh the page.',
                    PrintToolTip: 'Print',
                    RefreshToolTip: 'Refresh',
                    NavigateBackToolTip: 'Navigate back',
                    NavigateForwardToolTip: 'Navigate forward',
                    ReportParametersSelectAllText: '<select all>',
                    ReportParametersSelectAValueText: '<select a value>',
                    ReportParametersInvalidValueText: 'Invalid value.',
                    ReportParametersNoValueText: 'Value required.',
                    ReportParametersNullText: 'NULL',
                    ReportParametersPreviewButtonText: 'Preview',
                    ReportParametersFalseValueLabel: 'False',
                    ReportParametersInputDataError: 'Missing or invalid parameter value. Please input valid data for all parameters.',
                    ReportParametersTrueValueLabel: 'True',
                    MissingReportSource: 'The source of the report definition has not been specified.',
                    ZoomToPageWidth: 'Page Width',
                    ZoomToWholePage: 'Full Page'
                }, 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_ReportArea', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_SplitterCell', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_DocumentMapCell', true, true, 'PDF', 'ReportViewer1_RSID', true);
            </script>

  ...................
  ...................
</html>
```

The value is `a90a0d41efa6429eadfefa42fc529de1` and this is in the middle of this content:

```
'/app/Telerik.ReportViewer.axd', 'a90a0d41efa6429eadfefa42fc529de1', 'Percent', '100',
```

Whats the best way I can parse this value using Java?

Comment: If you're just trying to get rid of `a90a0d41efa6429eadfefa42fc529de1`, then you can use the string.replace(`", 'a90a0d41efa6429eadfefa42fc529de1"`, "") command.

Comment: LOL I am trying to extract this variable :)

Comment: You said "scrap" in your question so I wasn't sure what you were trying to do with it. :D

Comment: Using https://jsoup.org/ should get you the script text. Parsing the magic value could be just a matter of splitting the string, and grabbing the right index - and hoping the provider never changes the arg structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the HTML with String class

```
public class HtmlParser {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String result = getValuesProp(html);
        System.out.println("Result: "+ result);
    }

    static String PIVOT = "Telerik.ReportViewer.axd";

    public static String getValuesProp(String json) {
        String subString;

        int i = json.indexOf(PIVOT);
        i+= PIVOT.length();
        //', chars
        i+=2;
        subString = json.substring(i);

        i = subString.indexOf("'");
        i++;
        subString = subString.substring(i);
        i = subString.indexOf("'");
        subString = subString.substring(0,i);
        return subString;
    }

    static String html ="<html>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n" +
            "                var ReportViewer1 = new ReportViewer('ReportViewer1', 'ReportViewer1_ReportToolbar', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_WaitControl', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_ReportCell', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_PreviewFrame', 'ReportViewer1_ParametersAreaCell', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_ErrorControl', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_ErrorLabel', 'ReportViewer1_CP', '/app/Telerik.ReportViewer.axd', 'a90a0d41efa6429eadfefa42fc529de1', 'Percent', '100', '', 'ReportViewer1_EditorPlaceholder', 'ReportViewer1_CalendarFrame', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_DocumentMapCell', {\n" +
            "                    CurrentPageToolTip: 'STR_TELERIK_MSG_CUR_PAGE_TOOL_TIP',\n" +
            "                    ExportButtonText: 'Export',\n" +
            "                    ExportToolTip: 'Export',\n" +
            "                    ExportSelectFormatText: 'Export to the selected format',\n" +
            "                    FirstPageToolTip: 'First page',\n" +
            "                    LabelOf: 'of',\n" +
            "                    LastPageToolTip: 'Last Page',\n" +
            "                    ProcessingReportMessage: 'Generating report...',\n" +
            "                    NoPageToDisplay: 'No page to display.',\n" +
            "                    NextPageToolTip: 'Next page',\n" +
            "                    ParametersToolTip: 'Click to close parameters area|Click to open parameters area',\n" +
            "                    DocumentMapToolTip: 'Hide document map|Show document map',\n" +
            "                    PreviousPageToolTip: 'Previous page',\n" +
            "                    TogglePageLayoutToolTip: 'Switch to interactive view|Switch to print preview',\n" +
            "                    SessionHasExpiredError: 'Session has expired.',\n" +
            "                    SessionHasExpiredMessage: 'Please, refresh the page.',\n" +
            "                    PrintToolTip: 'Print',\n" +
            "                    RefreshToolTip: 'Refresh',\n" +
            "                    NavigateBackToolTip: 'Navigate back',\n" +
            "                    NavigateForwardToolTip: 'Navigate forward',\n" +
            "                    ReportParametersSelectAllText: '<select all>',\n" +
            "                    ReportParametersSelectAValueText: '<select a value>',\n" +
            "                    ReportParametersInvalidValueText: 'Invalid value.',\n" +
            "                    ReportParametersNoValueText: 'Value required.',\n" +
            "                    ReportParametersNullText: 'NULL',\n" +
            "                    ReportParametersPreviewButtonText: 'Preview',\n" +
            "                    ReportParametersFalseValueLabel: 'False',\n" +
            "                    ReportParametersInputDataError: 'Missing or invalid parameter value. Please input valid data for all parameters.',\n" +
            "                    ReportParametersTrueValueLabel: 'True',\n" +
            "                    MissingReportSource: 'The source of the report definition has not been specified.',\n" +
            "                    ZoomToPageWidth: 'Page Width',\n" +
            "                    ZoomToWholePage: 'Full Page'\n" +
            "                }, 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_ReportArea', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_SplitterCell', 'ReportViewer1_ReportArea_DocumentMapCell', true, true, 'PDF', 'ReportViewer1_RSID', true);\n" +
            "            </script>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "</html>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read the text a line at a time like how most files are read. Because the format will always be the same, you look for a line that begins with the characters "var ReportViewer1." Then you know you have found the line you want. You may need to strip some white space, although it will always be formatted with the same whitespace too (up to you really.)

When you have the line, use the String .split() method to split that line into an array. There are nice delimiters there to split on  ... "," or " " or ", " ... again, see what works best for you.

Test the split up line parts for '/app/Telerik.ReportViewer.axd' ... the next member of your split array will be the value you are looking for.

Again, the formatting will always be the same, so you can rely on that to find your variable. Of course, study the html text to make sure it does always follow the same format within the line you are investigating, but looking at it, I assume it probably does.

Again, find your line ... split it on a delimiter ... and use some logic to find the element you are after in the split up line parts.